# HTML reports is broken when its downloaded from github action using github artifact

Tags: github-actions, pytest-html, github-actions-artifacts

I am running my test into GitHub action and after test execution is completed I download generated report using `github/action-artifact` and when I open that report design is broken.

My report is in the below format when I generate it from my local.
[image]

and when I download reports from GitHub action it looks like the below format.

[image]

What is the problem can anyone know?

Comment: it looks like some css styling is missing.  when you run locally, is the report completely self contained in the one html file or does it reference other files?

Comment: No it's not reference others file when i run it locally

Comment: have you diff'ed the two files?

Comment: @bryanmac sorry?

Answer (score 0):

Please look up the header in the html report generated by pytest-html, it holds:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YOUR TITLE</title>
    <link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

If you have screenshots (using Extras), they are located in basedir.

The rest I believe is enclosed in the *.html file.

Comment: Yes i have `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test Report</title>
    <link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></head>` in my `report.html` file. But design in broken when report generated in `github action`